Search Service and User Profile setup and configuration
I just setup a SharePoint 2019 server, As I am configuring it first time I am confused do I need to setup a Search service or the search and user profile will automatically working !!
The setup is in three tier architecture.
Please suggest the best practice as well for these and other services.
